# Method with Interface Parameters with Mockito Argument Capture

Tags: java, junit, mocking, mockito

I've one simple question. I've got two classes

`XMessage` and `YMessage`. These two classes are the sub class of `ZClass`.

These messages are published from a `PublisherService` with method

```
public void publish(ZClass message, Properties props){
     // some lowlevel stuff.
     // note that method is taking ZClass as an arg.
}
```

According to my logic `XMessage` is sent many times while `YMessage` is sent only once in one test.

Let's say `XMessage` is supposed to be sent 4 times where `YMessage` is sent 1 time. I would assume below code would work.

```
        ArgumentCaptor<XMessage> xCaptor = ArgumentCaptor.forClass(XMessage.class);

        verify(publisherService, times(4)).sendMessage(isA(XMessage.class),any());
        verify(publisherService, times(1)).sendMessage(isA(YMessage.class),any());
        verify(publisherService, times(4)).sendMessage(xCaptor,any());
```

However it fails with captor and the captor has 5 values.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using Mockito's ArgumentCaptor class to match a child class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5403706/using-mockitos-argumentcaptor-class-to-match-a-child-class)

Comment: I checked this one already, and no it does not.

Comment: Fair enough. I thought it would as one answer it explains where the problem inside mockito is: public boolean matches always says true. so the captor says yes to any class. To fix it you'll likely have to verify by hand it is xMessage and not yMessage. I would expect if you were to do xCaptor.get() for all 5 answers you would get the classcast exception the poster of that issue is mentioning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a known issue in Mockito. The issue is that `ArgumentCaptor` is not type aware.

See https://github.com/mockito/mockito/issues/565

This is open from 2016 and still not fully fixed so I would just did some workaround around it.

You can capture all of the arguments and then `instanceof` just the ones you need.

```java
ArgumentCaptor<ZClass> zCaptor = ArgumentCaptor.forClass(ZClass.class);

Mockito.verify(publisherService, times(5)).publish(zCaptor.capture(), ArgumentMatchers.<Properties>any());

List<XMessage> xMessages = zCaptor.getAllValues()
                                  .stream()
                                  .filter(arg -> arg instanceof XMessage)
                                  .map(arg -> (XMessage) arg)
                                  .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: Oh well... I actually did this workaround and looked back at the code thought it was an overkill for a simple purpose.

Comment: The issue was closed https://github.com/mockito/mockito/issues/565 . I'm not sure with version it was included.